# How to get Either left/right depending of Option value

Tags: java, either, vavr

I'm trying to return `Either` value depending on option value. My goal is to return Either.right() if the option is present otherwise, the code should return Either.left(). 
I use Java 8 and vavr 0.9.2

I want to avoid conditional imbrication

```java
public Either<String, Integer> doSomething() {
    Optional<Integer> optionalInteger = Optional.of(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    Option<Integer> integerOption = Option.ofOptional(optionalInteger);

    return integerOption.map(value -> {
      //some other actions here
      return Either.right(value);
    }).orElse(() -> {
      //some other checks her also 
      return Either.left("Error message");
    });
}
```

the compiler fail with this message

```
Error:(58, 7) java: no suitable method found for orElse(()->Either[...]age"))
    method io.vavr.control.Option.orElse(io.vavr.control.Option<? extends io.vavr.control.Either<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Integer>>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; io.vavr.control.Option is not a functional interface
          multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface io.vavr.control.Option)
    method io.vavr.control.Option.orElse(java.util.function.Supplier<? extends io.vavr.control.Option<? extends io.vavr.control.Either<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Integer>>>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
          no instance(s) of type variable(s) L,R exist so that io.vavr.control.Either<L,R> conforms to io.vavr.control.Option<? extends io.vavr.control.Either<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Integer>>)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`orElse` returns `Option<T>` while `doSomething` return type requires `Either<String, Integer>`.

Instead, try to use `getOrElse` which returns `T`:

```
public Either<String, Integer> doSomething() {
    // ...
    return integerOption.map(
        Either::<String, Integer>right).getOrElse(
            () -> Either.left("Error message"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but with getOrElse, there is no way to infer Either<String,Integer> it always infers Either<Object,Integer>

Error:(59, 17) java: incompatible types: io.vavr.control.Either<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to io.vavr.control.Either<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>

Comment: Yes, that's why you need to provide an explicit type argument: `Either::<String, Integer>right`, no matter it is `getOrElse` or `orElse`.

Comment: I believe it's called `orElseGet`, not `getOrElse` in java ;)

Comment: @Klesun No, as it's a [vavr api method](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/control/Option.html#getOrElse-T-).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to return `Either<...>` not an `Option<Either<...>>` you have to use [getOrElse](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/control/Option.html#getOrElse-java.util.function.Supplier-)

Answer (score 0):

I think redundant generics and formatting in @oleksandr-pyrohov's answer overcomplicate things a bit. I'd just write it this way instead:

```java
public Either<String, Integer> doSomething() {
    // ...
    return integerOption
        .map(Either::right)
        .orElseGet(() -> Either.left("Error message"));
}
```

Upd.: though it does not seem to always infer generics on it's own sadly.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
public Either<String, Integer> doSomething() {
// ...
return integerOption
    .<Either<String, Integer>>map(Either::right)
    .orElseGet(() -> Either.left("Error message"));
}
```